# I need to make a jQuery dialog appear when the page is loaded for the first time and not again after that

Tags: php, jquery, html

```
<?php
    //Set session var as null
    session_start();

    if(!isset($_SESSION['view'])){
        $_SESSION['view']= 1;
    }else{
        $_SESSION['view']++;
    }

    //If it is the first time the site is being opened
    if ($_SESSION['view'] == 1) {   
        //Show the dialog & reset the var as not null
        echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">";
        echo "jQuery(document).ready(function($){";               


        echo "$(\"#dialog-1\").dialog({";

        echo "draggable: false,";
        echo "modal: true,";
        echo "autoOpen: true,";

        echo "});";

        echo "});";

        echo "</script>";


        $_SESSION['view']++;
    ?>
        <div id="dialog-1">
            Registration now open
        </div>
<?php

    }

     unset($_SESSION['view']);

?>
```

The session needs to re-set when the user reloads or exits the page. I have gotten the dialog to show but the $_SESSION['view'] variable is not being incremented. Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Isn't it the natural behavior of `sessions`?
you can use `cookies`.

Comment: Why don't use a client side persistent data as cookie/local storage?

Comment: I tried local storage and got the same result

Comment: As such I see no reason why your counter wouldn't be incremented, but your session won't be reset on page leave/reload, because they are specifically meant to be persistent.

Comment: @Celeste But you need to keep cache, not clearing it

Comment: remove this `unset($_SESSION['view']);` ... when you unset it, then next time they refresh it won't be set! So it will show it again. Don't unset it.

Comment: That works but then when the page is reloaded it isnt reset so it just keeps  incrementing

Comment: I have never used local storage before ive tried. This is the code ive tried to use:    echo "if(localStorage.getItem(\"firstTime\")==null){";
       //alert("First Time Alert");
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">";
    echo "jQuery(document).ready(function($){";               
 
  
    echo "$(\"#dialog-1\").dialog({";
      
    echo "draggable: false,";
    echo "modal: true,";
    echo "autoOpen: true,";
 
    echo "});";
  
    echo "});";
 
    echo "</script>";
       echo "localStorage.setItem(\"firstTime\",\"done\");";
   echo "}";

Comment: @Celeste Isn't that what you want? That it keeps incrementing for each view after the first?

Comment: No, i need the first time the page is opened by anyone it needs to show. If the page is closed and then opened again it needs to show again but not if you go to another page and then come back to this page. If that makes any sense.

Comment: @Celeste can you put mine one suggestion without you php code and try to see what happens.

Comment: I tried it without the php code and nothing is happening

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of using localStorage I used sessionStorage and this fixed the problem.

Comment: put the solution here.

Answer (score 3):

you can use it with html5 localstorage in jquery.

here is a solution

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){  
    if (localStorage.getItem("view") === null) {
       localStorage.setItem("view", "true");
       //your code here
            $("#dialog-1").dialog({
            draggable: false,
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: true,
        });
    }            
});
```

and for resetting it for next open

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
      localStorage.removeItem('view');
      return '';
});
```

Comment: I tried this it works but still i need it to re-set when the page is closed.

Comment: Oki that works perfectly but my browser is asking me to leave the page. Thanks so much!

Comment: can you try it with putting return or not.